# How I order my text and icon in a card (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, card

here is my currently code:

```
body: Scaffold(
              body: Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
            child: Container(
              width: 400,
              height: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.ice_skating,
                          size: 30,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Hi",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 5,
                        ),
                        Text("spots",
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ))),
```

but i want it like this:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I suspect you want some of your `Column`s to be `Row`s. In case you didn't know, a `Column` lays out its children vertically and a `Row` horizontally

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd Column you have used should be a Row

```
body: Scaffold(
          body: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        shape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
        child: Container(
          width: 400,
          height: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.ice_skating,
                      size: 30,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,//this line is important for providing equal space
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Hi",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Text("spots",
                        style:
                            TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)))
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ))),
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Result]

```
  Card(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
        child: Container(
          width: 400,
          height: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  'Text',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "spots",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      "Hi",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.ice_skating,
                      size: 30,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return Scaffold(
              body: Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
            child: Container(
              width: 400,
              height: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                         Text(
                          "Hi",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Hi",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                       
                        Text("spots",
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6))),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.ice_skating,
                          size: 30,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ));
```

**Output**

[image]